# Can I use Django Authentication with Vue

Tags: python, django, vue.js

I can use Django Authentication with creating an html file in registration/login.html and it works perfectly fine. But I want to use it with a different front end, Vue, so I just want to call the endpoint /accounts/login, but it throws page does not exist error.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: We'll need a bit more of information in order to help you. Could you edit your question and include, for example, the piece of front-end code making the request to the login endpoint? I would make sure you're pointing to the right server (e.g localhost:8000) and the URL path is correct (you might need to append a slash at the end).

Comment: @MoisésHiraldo I decided to use Djoser, thank you anyway